# how to make class variables not reset when closing unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a game where the user can input term and definition pairs and save them after the game closes.

These variables are in a script attached to a manager object.

```cs
    public Dictionary<string, string> TermDefinitionPairs;
    public Dictionary<string, int> TermPriorityValuePairs;
    public List<string> unseenTerms;

    private void AddTerm(string term, string definition)
    {
        TermDefinitionPairs[term] = definition;
        unseenTerms.Add(term);
        // Debug.Log(unseenTerms.Count);
    }
```

How can I make them save even after the game closes? I tried to use playerprefs but they can't hold those data structures.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html

Answer (score 0):

You can save it as a JSON file (serialize) and then load it on the next time (deserialize) to get all the data you need.

[Here](https://prasetion.medium.com/saving-data-as-json-in-unity-4419042d1334) is an example of this.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

i use this video.[Save load system in unity](https://youtu.be/XOjd_qU2Ido)

in this way you need to save variables to binary file. but i tested and it works good.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).